# How to test if a word is masculine or feminine in Arabic in VBA

Tags: vba, arabic

How to test if a word is masculine or feminine in Arabic in VBA?

The word is a String.

Result should be True or False for masculine or feminine.

Example: "شمس" become feminine

"قمر" becomes masculine

This simple code does not work at all:

```
Sex = "M"
If Right(word, 1) = "ة" Then Sex = "F"
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your current code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For any language, you try to determine the rules for masculine or feminine and then apply them to the word. Sometimes it might be a probabilistic guess. Often regular expressions can help. If you can provide these rules, we might be able to help.

Comment: What does `Right(word, 1)` return? Because Arabic is RTL, you might actually need `Left(word, 1)` to correspond to the glyph sequence.

Comment: it returns the last letter of the word, i.e. ending letter of the word

Comment: I don't speak Arabic but: 1) for example in French, mouse is said "souris": it's impossible to guess whether it's masculine or feminine unless you don't know it. Same goes for many other languages that are not English. I guess in Arabic you'd have tons of these exceptions, how would you handle them? 2) what if they pass along a verb, or something that is not a noun? 
You're trying to code an Arabic dictionary in VBA, that's ambitious but I think it'd be more realistic for you to make an API call to some online dictionary and get the result from there.

Comment: I am not an Arabic speaker, but a quick Google search seemed to say that the rules for determining gender may be complex and contextual. You would likely need to some sort of lookup table or rule-based logic -- or even a website that you could access with an API to request word information (including gender). This [master's thesis paper](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~rrgpage/rrg/Yasser_Salem_MSc_thesis.pdf) goes into greater detail that I can understand, but may be of help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the only thing determining the gender of a word are its ending you can use select case (simple example for german):

The number in Right() determines how many characters you want to look at.

```
Public Function isMale(aWord As String) As Boolean
    Select Case True
        Case Right(aWord, 2) = "er"
            isMale = True
        Case Right(aWord, 2) = "in"
            isMale = False
        End Select
End Function
```